# Как происходит получение rgb картинки?

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, как работает данный метод класса BufferedImage

```
 public int[] getRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h,
                    int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На эту тему есть много англоязычных ответов:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761438/understanding-bufferedimage-getrgb-output-values например.

Точно могу сказать что `int startX` - координата х, `int startY` - координата у, `int w, int h` - значение ширины (width - w) и значение высоты (height - h), численный массив `int[] rgbArray` - RGB код в формате 3 чисел (красный, зеленый, синий).